# Background color leaking of an element with border-radius in IE 10

Tags: internet-explorer-10, css

[image]

Elements with "border-radius" rule in IE10 are having some kind of "background color leaking" at the left-side of themselves. So i've been trying to figure out why these glitches appear and whether there any workaround for this behaviour or not. Any ideas?
The css rule "backgroung-clip" seems not to do any difference.
Here you can test and behold it by yourself: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/html5/borderradius/default.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not IE10, it's your machine.

Comment: Possibly it was problem with video card drivers on that machine.

Answer (score 0):

The problem must be of a different nature. My IE10 doesn't have any rendering problems. Everything displays just fine, even with the IE9 compatibility mode and document mode.